# Thousand Separator custom Positioning

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 13 with Visual Studio 2013. I want my numeric field type as 22,33,45,405.33 instead of 223,345,405.33. I googled all day long. What I found is that create formulas for this fields and convert to string with format. But why is the option **Thousand Separator** in the following picture?

[image]

Is it not possible to add rules in **Thousand Separator**, so that I can customize the position of the separator? If yes, what is the syntax of the rule? If no, what is the reason to keep an option **Thousand Separator** there and there is an option on the right side to apply rule?

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a thousand separator and by that Crystal separates number by thousands, not by your desired format.

You would like to get `22,33,45,405.33` but if you look last 5 digits `405.33`  you can see that you separate by thousand and then by hundreds. Just convert your number to string and then put separators depending on your number length `xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xxx.xx` etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks KuKeC for your quick answer.But how and where can i write that?please let me know